# Training Mode: NPC on control option

Tags: wii-u, super-smash-bros-4

When I go in training mode I know that somehow you are able to make the NPC do an action when it's on the control option. I just don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply press **start** and in the menu you can change the **CPU Behavior**. If you want to control the CPU manually you have to plug-in another controller.

Comment: I know that, but there is an option to put it on control, and you can make it do stuff in this state, that isn't already an option.

Comment: @LumaForSmash Have you tried using another controller. IF I recall correctly in Brawl you could control the differente CPU spawned in training mode with more controller.

Comment: There we go that worked, too bad no one is really here to help me. Thanks anyway.